# shortest distance between point and line (point w/ direction vector) in 3d using Python

Tags: python, line, distance, point

In a 3-dimensional Cartesian coordinate system, given

```
    line A: point with known coordinates and direction vector
    point B with known coordinates
```

I need to determine the shortest distance between point B and line A.  I can do this manually on a point-by-point basis using algebra, but I am having difficulty making it iterable due to the necessarily different equations (and parameters) for each set of points.  Ideally I'm looking for a single command or 2-3 functions from {math, numpy, et al.} that can be strung together to achieve this goal.  Thanks.

Comment: Why would you use iteration at all?  The distance between a point and a line in 3D has a [closed-form solution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html).

Comment: Just remember your time at school, and how you calculated distances in analytic geometry back then. Then implement this same algorithm in python.

Comment: @TimPeters  Thanks for the tip.  Using that suggestion, I changed my code around a bit: 
cross = numpy.cross(l2-l1,l1-p);
d = numpy.sqrt(numpy.vdot(cross,cross))/numpy.sqrt(numpy.vdot(l2-l1,l2-l1));
where l2 and l1 are numpy arrays representing points on a line, and p is the third point.  The only thing that seems odd is that I'm using the direction vector to generate the second point, but it works.  Thanks again.

Comment: You can use the norm from numpy.linalg:
d = norm(np.cross(l2-l1, l1-p))/norm(l2-l1)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the point-line distance is just given by the length of the line segment perpendicular to line `A`.

You can use the [scikit-spatial](https://scikit-spatial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library for that:

```py
from skspatial.objects import Line, Point

# Define line A
line_A = Line(point=Point([5, 2, -3]), direction=Vector([3, 8, 2]))

# Compute distance form point B (for instance, given by the coordinates [5, -5, 3])
distance = line.distance_point([5, -5, 3])
```